# How to get IP address of the launched instance with Boto

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto, openstack

I am launching instance in openstack using boto

```
myinstance = conn.run_instances('ami-0000007d',min_count=1,max_count=1, instance_type = 'm1.small')

newmachine=myinstance.instances[0]
```

newMachine has the info related to the launched instance. I have tried

```
vars(newmachine)
```

and the ip_address and private_ip_address of variables are empty. How can I obtain the ip_address of the launched instance ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Refresh the value until the instance enters Running state. At that point, the IP should be present (not that there's anything you could do with the IP before the instance is in running state).

```
reservation = conn.run_instances(...)

instance = reservation.instances[0]

while instance.update() != "running":
    time.sleep(5)  # Run this in a green thread, ideally

print instance.ip_address
```

Comment: I had a problem with this and calling `instance.update()` again 5 seconds after it entered "running" state solved it.

Comment: Can an instance not have multiple ip addresses?

Comment: if you want the private IP address, you can use instance.private_ip_address