# How to access EMR master private ip address using pure python / boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, emr

I've searched on this site and google but have not been able to get an answer for this.

I have code running from an EC2 instance which creates and manager EMR clusters using boto.
I can use this framework to get the flow_id (or cluster_id, not sure which is the right name for it), it start with "j-" and has a fixed amount of chars to identify the cluster.

Using the framework I can establish an emr or ec2 connection, but for the life of me I cannot do the following using boto:

```
    aws emr --list-clusters --cluster-id=j-ASDFGHJKL | json '["instances"].[0].["privateipaddress"]
```

**The above is a little fudged, I cannot remember the json format and what the json command is or what args it wants, but cli nonetheless.

I've pprint.pprint()'ed and inspected with inspect.getmembers() the connections, getting the conn to the specific cluster_id, but I have yet to see this field/var/attribute with or without method calls.

I've been up and down amazon and boto, how do they do it like
[here](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/boto/boto/.PipPackage/boto/.def/tests/unit/emr/test_connection/TestListSteps/default_body)?

In the

```
    def test_list_instances(self): #line 317
        ...
        self.assertEqual(response.instances[0].privateipaddress , '10.0.0.60')
        ...
```

P.S. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547010/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-launched-instance-with-boto) but python complains that "instances" property is not iterable, array accessable (i forget the "var[0]" naming), and something else I tried, including inspecting.
BTW, i can access the publicDNSaddress from here, and many other things, just not the privateIP...

Please tell me if I messup up somewhere and where I can find the answer, i'm using an ugly fix by using subprocess!

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking for taking master ip of emr then below commands will work:

```
list_intance_resp =  boto3.client('emr',region_name='us-east-1').list_instances(ClusterId ='j-XXXXXXX')
print list_intance_resp['Instances'][len(list_intance_resp['Instances'])-1]['PrivateIpAddress']
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of boto using 
`pip show boto`
My guess is your using a version 2.24 or earlier as this version did not parse instance information see https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/2.24.0/tests/unit/emr/test_connection.py#L117
compared to
https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/2.25.0/tests/unit/emr/test_connection.py#L313

If you upgrade your version of boto to 2.25 or newer you'll be able to do the following

```
from boto.emr.connection import EmrConnection

conn = EmrConnection(<your aws key>, <your aws secret key>)
jobid = 'j-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' # your job id
response = conn.list_instances(jobid)

for instance in response.instances:
    print instance.privateipaddress
```

Comment: For boto3 it'll be `import boto3

client = boto3.client('emr', region_name='us-east-1')

response = client.list_instances(ClusterId='j-1KWURUMOCK57F')

print response`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to query the master instances from the Master Instance Group with the help of the EMR cluster-ID. If you have more than one master, you can parse the boto3 output and take the IP if the first listed master.

Your Boto3 execution environment should have access to EMR describe a cluster and its instance groups. Here is the

```
emr_list_instance_rep = boto_client_emr.list_instances(
    ClusterId=cluster_id,
    InstanceGroupTypes=[
        'MASTER',
    ],
    InstanceStates=[
        'RUNNING',
    ]
)

return emr_list_instance_rep["Instances"][0]["PrivateIpAddress"]
```

You can find the full boto3 script and its explanation here https://scriptcrunch.com/script-retrieve-aws-emr-master-ip/